# NLog's WebService target: How to sequentially send the requests?

Tags: silverlight, nlog

I use NLog's WebService target in Silverlight and run into a problem if the logging service is unavailable.

What happens is that all calls to the logging service hang for a long time until they time out.

This is firstly ugly and secondly problematic in the face of a request limit, which I have under my given circumstances. After the request limit is reached due to several pending logging requests, the application also fails to make requests that are not logging related.

Ideally I'd like a WebService target that sends the requests sequentially, but I can't configure it to do that, can I?

Since I have full control about the logging server I could also move to a different target, but I'd rather have a purely configuration-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some time back I implemented a logging target like that for Silverlight.  We were using Common.Logging for .NET and it did not support Silverlight.  So, we ported part of Common.Logging to Silverlight and implemented a "logging service adapter" to send our logging messages to a logging service.  I implemented a logging queue using the producer/consumer pattern.  Maybe you will find it useful.

In the end, the project that I was working on when I implemented this didn't go anywhere, so this particular piece of code is not in use.

[Using WCF service via async interface from worker thread, how do I ensure that events are sent from the client "in order"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136808/using-wcf-service-via-async-interface-from-worker-thread-how-do-i-ensure-that-e)